# Arch Linux with PCI Passthrough freezes on boot after upgrade

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kvm, pci-passthrough

I have been running arch linux with [PCI Passthrough](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF) for several months now, and just updated a few days ago.  When I rebooted, arch always freezes during boot.

The only way I can get it to boot is to remove the option "**intel_iommu=on**" from my kernel modules, in which case it will continue to boot.  I have tried downgrading to linux-lts with no luck. I can get the machine to boot without IOMMU on, but I do need it working.

> Kernel: 4.13.12-1
>
> GPUs: 1080ti(vfio - passthrough), 1050ti(host), AMD 570X (odd setup I know)

The only other thing that has changed is I added the AMD card today, but I tried removing and/or blacklisting amdgpu to no affect.

Comment: It might be helpful to know precisely when during boot the freeze happens. This might be visible in `syslog` with judicious grepping. I'm guessing this might happen when  X starts (as such looking at X's logs could be useful).

Comment: It always get to where *I think* it's loading kernel modules - says "loading lvm" then freezes.  Is there anything specific I should grep for?

Comment: So you really want the last lines before the crash (normally identified by a big time gap). I'm guess from the above that you can't boot into single user mode without it hanging. One thing you can do is drop into a shell during the initrd phase to do some tweaking, though I'm not sure how useful this would be this case.

Comment: Ok, is that something I can get with journalctl, or do I specifically need syslog for that?

Comment: Everything should be in `journalctl`. I might do something like `sudo journalctl  | grep -o '^.............' | uniq -c ` to identify when the reboot happened and then look at what happened around that time.

Comment: The easy solution is to discover what package is causing the problem rollback and wait for someone else discover the bug and create a work around :).

Comment: Ok, I did find the following at different times during boot:

microcode: late loading on model 79 is disabled. . . still looking

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what did it, I might just start downgrading and hope I find it

Comment: Ok, I figured out what I believe to be the problem.  I forgot I had also moved the GPU being passed through to the first slot on my motherboard, and that was causing some kind of lock up since it would try to use that as the display, and the once actually loading the kernel it would also be trying to pass through the GPU.